# Python print function doesn't work

Tags: python

I have followed [this](http://ttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg) tutorial. But I do have a small question.

I have copied the exact code in de text editor, and I have the exact same settings in Glade. But when I click the refresh button, I dont see the text in de terminal. What am I doing wrong? I have an error in Glade that says: This property was introduced in gtk+3.10 while project targets gtk+3.0

Running: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Glade 3.16.1

gedit 3.10.4

```
    self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
self.backbutton = self.builder.get_object("backbutton")
self.nextbutton = self.builder.get_object("nextbutton")
self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
self.scrolledwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("toolbar")

context = self.toolbar.get_style_context()
context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)

self.webview = WebKit.WebView()

self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
self.webview.show()

def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.reload()
    print ("refresh")

def on_backbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.back()
    print "back"

def on_nextbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.next()
    print "next"

def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
    url = widget.get_text()

    print url

    self.webview.open(url)
```

I would love to here from you!

Answer (score 0):

First: You are not linking the tutorial... I found that you double posted, and the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg

The error does not come from the print function, and you are using python 2.x, because otherwise you would get a different error:

```
>>> help()
Welcome to Python 3.4's help utility!
```

[...]

```
>>> print "refresh"
File "<input>", line 1
print "refresh"
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I think the error is not even in the code you have posted above. To debug this, try to do the followign:

1. Check the correct error message - it should also give you a file name and line number
2. Check that file/line for the error

That is the way to debug python (or any other language) code...

I understand the error message to say that you are using functionality which is not available in your version of the library - once you know the exact line which causes the error you might want to check the reference documentation.

Comment: I replaced the link. Thanks for noticing! 
I have no error messages in the terminal or what so ever. And the code has no difference from the video. I really don't see what is wrong with the code.

Comment: There is no error message. The terminal doesn't say aything when I click on the refreshbutton (when I execute the Refreshbutton function).